# how do i find and convert link tags to @import tags inside a textarea using jquery and/or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

As the title says, i have an text input area that defines a few css stylesheets. I'm looking to find and replace all link tags with @import tags inside the text input area. I need some javascript function which will fire off a click of an image.

Any ideas on how to structure the function to do the find and replace?

Thanks!

P.S. here is an example. I need the following to go from this:

```
<textarea rows="30" cols="30" name="code">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />

</textarea>
```

to this:

```
<textarea rows="30" cols="30" name="code">
@import url("stylesheet.css");</textarea>
```

Comment: could you write some stub code like, you want to change what to what!!

Comment: i added the code at the top in the main questions. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('pleaseGiveYourTextareaAnID');
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(new RegExp('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="(.*)" />', 'g'), '@import url("$1");');
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: The only thing your excellent, pure JS, version needs is a 'g' flag on that RegExp so that all the OP's LINK tags become imports, instead of only the first.

Comment: @JAAulde: Thanks, missed that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a pure jQuery version: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/E8WW3/3/

```js
var $textarea = $( 'textarea[name="code"]' );

$textarea.val(
    $( '<div>' )
        .html( $textarea.val() )
        .find( 'link[rel="stylesheet"][type="text/css"]' )
            .each( function()
            {
                var $this = $( this );
                $this.replaceWith( '@import url("' + $this.attr( 'href' ) + '");' );
            } )
            .end()
        .html()
);
```

```css
@import url("stylesheet1.css");
    jhg jhjh 
   jhgh hjgk g 
   @import url("stylesheet2.css");
@import url("stylesheet3.css");
    b kj 
    jhvh gjfvjk guy m
guyyu    
    @import url("stylesheet4.css");vj hj
,mh jkh kjgh
    @import url("stylesheet5.css");
    bhjbhj
```

```html
<textarea rows="30" cols="30" name="code">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css" />
    jhg jhjh 
   jhgh hjgk g 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet3.css" />
    b kj 
    jhvh gjfvjk guy m
guyyu    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet4.css" />vj hj
,mh jkh kjgh
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet5.css" />
    bhjbhj
</textarea>
```